# Euler characteristic singular surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, singularity-theory

The setting is the one of algebraic curves over the complex numbers. It is known that in an irreducible nodal curve each node reduces the arithmetic genus by one: if $\tilde{C} \rightarrow C$ is the normalization of $C$, and $C$ is nodal with $n$ nodes, then $p_a(\tilde{C})=p_a(C)-n$. I am using the word reduce because I am mainly thinking of a plane curve: if it has degree $d$ and it is smooth, then it has genus
\begin{equation}
p_g=p_a=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2},
\end{equation} 
while if it is nodal with $n$ nodes, the genus of the normalization is 
\begin{equation}
p_g=p_a=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}-n.
\end{equation}

The above statement can be proved thinking of our irreducible nodal curve $C$ as being in some smooth surface $S$, using adjunction formula on $S$ and on its blow up at the nodes of $C$.

My question is the following. Can we show this fact using the topological Euler characteristic? Does the topological Euler characteristic make sense if $C$ is singular, and is it still equal to $2(1-p_a(C))$?

**Edit:** PVAL's comment shows that the above thing does not work for reducible curves. If we take as definition of $p_a$ the one given in Hartshorne (chapter 3, section 5, exercises), then $p_a(C)=h^1(\mathcal{O}_C)$ for a reducible curve too. If we consider $C=L_1 \cup L_2 \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, then we have $h^1(\mathcal{O}_{L_1\cup L_2})=0$ from the long exact sequence in cohomology of $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-2)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{L_1 \cup L_2}\rightarrow 0$. On the other hand, $\chi_{top}(L_1 \cup L_2)=3 \neq 2 (1-0)$.

Comment: The union of two distinct lines in $\Bbb P^2$ is homeomorphic to a wedge of 2 spheres which has Euler characteristic $3$. Does this work in this case?

Comment: @PVAL I am thinking of irreducible nodal curves, I will edit the question! Thanks!

Comment: @PVAL Is the topological Euler characteristic of the nodal cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ equal to 1? If so the answer to my question should be no, since if $C$ denotes the nodal cubic, $h^1(\mathcal{O}_C)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topological Euler characteristic of a singular curve is not always even. In fact, if $\tilde{C}$ is the normalization of $C$, then $\chi(C)=\chi(\tilde C)-n$ where $n$ is the number of nodal points. Indeed, let $x$ be a nodal point of $C$ and $C_x$ be the blow-up of $C$ at $x$. Then, the cartesian and cocartesian square 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\{x_1,x_2\}@>>> C_x\\
@VVV@VVV\\
x@>>>C
\end{CD}
$$
gives a long exact sequence in cohomology :
$$ \dots\rightarrow H^n(C)\rightarrow H^n(C_x)\oplus H^n(x)\rightarrow H^n(\{x_1,x_2\})\rightarrow H^{n+1}(C)\rightarrow\dots $$
In particular $\chi(C)+\chi(\{x_1,x_2\})=\chi(\{x\})+\chi(C_x)$. And because the characteristic of a point is $1$, $\chi(C)=\chi(C_x)-1$. By induction on the number of nodes, you get $\chi(C)=\chi(\tilde{C})-n$.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this old question, but do you have a reference for this long exact sequence? When I apply this to the normalization of a nodal cubic I'm getting that the nodal cubic has $h^1 = 3$, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @stupid_question_bot How do you get $h^1=3$ ? You should have $h^1=1$ right ?

Comment: I agree the correct answer indeed should be $h^1 = 1$, but if I'm not mistaken the dimensions of the terms of your exact sequence are: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 2 -> $h^1(C)$ -> 2 -> $0 = h^1(\{x_1,x_2\})$, which seems to give $h^1(C) = 3$?

Comment: @stupid_question_bot But $h^1(C_x)=0$ and not 2, since the normalization of the nodal curve is a $\mathbb{P}^1$. So the sequence does give $h^1(C)=1$.

Comment: Ah of course, stupid mistake. Do you have a reference for this long exact sequence? (or even a name that I can google?)

Comment: Maybe Blow-up exact sequence ? It has been a while since I've done this kind of mathematics. I don't know any references. I believe this is quite obvious from Mayer-Vietoris. Just compare the two MV sequences for $C$ where $U$ is a small neighborhood of $x$, $V=C\setminus x$, and for $C_x$ with the pull back of $U$ and $V$.